# How to create cohesive Spatial Pixels from Spatial Points Dataset

Tags: raster, r, coordinates

I have a Spatial Point DF `spo` (covering an irregular shaped area of interest). The data are not on a regular grid due to CRS transformation.

My goal is a raster with predefined resolution and extent of the area of interest (more spatial point data are to be mapped on this master raster).

Problems start when I

```
rasterize(spo, raster(ncol, nrow, extent, crs), spo$param)
```

I need to adjust `nrow`and `ncol` in a way so that I won't get moire patterns of NAs within my area of interest. I can't use a predefined (higher) resolution.

As a solution to this, I thought I would need some kind of Spatial Pixel DF `spi`, that covers my whole area of interest (just like *meuse.grid* in `library(raster); data(meuse.grid)`), and serves as a master grid. Then, I can use it to interpolate my data, e.g.

```
idw(param~1,spo,spi)
```

and by this, get full cover of my area of interest at my chosen resolution. But how can a SpatialPixelsDataFrame be produced from the point data?

So in my view, the question boils down to: How to produce *meuse.grid* from *meuse* dataset?

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach here, so please let me know if more easily can achieved what I'm after, using a different way.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, to interpolate a new grid from irregular data you need a base grid first that covers the region at a sensible resolution. You can do this pretty easily by hand using the tools, but take a look at trip::makeGridTopology for a stab at generalizing it while keeping all the options open. You still need to generate the Data part but it's not hard. If this sounds right I will answer with an example and wrapper function (that might be more generally useful).

Comment: @mdsumner, trip::makeGridTopology looks promising. If you could provide an example, I would really really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is create a convex hull around the source points in `spo`, and sample in that polygon using `spsample`. This function allows you to prescribe the gridcell size, see [this function](https://bitbucket.org/paulhiemstra/automap/src/d0e7a5c061a75fdb7a063238150ccac380ecb7ab/R/create_new_data.r?at=automap) in `automap` for an example (disclaimer, I wrote automap).

The next step would be to interpolate the values, e.g. using `automap`:

```
library(automap)
loadMeuse()
kr = autoKrige(log(zinc)~1, meuse, convex_hull_grid)
```

This uses kriging (Ordinary Kriging in this case) to fit a variogram model to the data and interpolate the values in `meuse` to the grid in `convex_hull_grid`.