# Interpolating SpatialPointsDataFrame to RasterLayer using autoKrige in R

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, kriging

I have a SpatialPointsDataFrame with elevation data and 51'257 elements. I also have a RasterLayer object of dimensions c(114,210) covering roughly the same area (all the spatial points are within the raster). I now would like to interpolate the spatial points to a grid of the same size and resolution as my RasterLayer object. In particular, I would like to use the automap::autoKrige() function to do so.

Here is how I proceed:

```
# generate dummy data:
x.vals <- runif(n = 51257, min = 2603330, max = 2608098)
y.vals <- runif(n = 51257, min = 1135929, max = 1138178)
elevation.vals <- rnorm(n = 51257, mean = 0, sd = 1)

# make a SpatialPointsDataFrame from dummy data:
elevation.spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = cbind(x.vals,y.vals), 
                                       data = data.frame(elevation.vals), 
                                       proj4string = CRS("+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"))

# generate a dummy raster:
my.raster <- raster(nrows = 114, ncols = 210, xmn = 383187.5, xmx = 388437.5, 
                    ymn = 5136362, ymx = 5139212, vals = NULL, 
                    crs = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")

# reproject the SpatialPointsDataFrame to the target raster projection
elevation.spdf.reproj <- spTransform(x = elevation.spdf, CRSobj = CRS(my.raster@crs@projargs))

# create a new_data object of type sp to be used in the autoKrige() function:
spatial.points <- SpatialPoints(coords = coordinates(my.raster), 
                                proj4string = CRS(my.raster@crs@projargs))
spatial.grid <- SpatialPixels(points = spatial.points)

# now do the interpolation:
automap::autoKrige(formula = elevation.vals ~ x.vals + y.vals, 
                   input_data = elevation.spdf.reproj, 
                   new_data = spatial.grid)
```

However, when I do that, I get the following error from the autoKrige function:

```
Error in locs[valid.pattern, ] : (subscript) logical subscript too long
In addition: Warning messages:
1: 'newdata' had 23940 rows but variables found have 51257 rows 
2: 'newdata' had 23940 rows but variables found have 51257 rows
```

It seems that my SpatialPointsDataFrame has too many elements.
Alternatively, I tried the approach described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43801/how-to-create-cohesive-spatial-pixels-from-spatial-points-dataset/45044#45044), producing a convex hull around my spatial points to interpolate to. However, I get a similar error message:

```
automap::autoKrige(formula = bedrock.vals ~ x.vals + y.vals, 
                   input_data = elevation.spdf.reproj, 
                   new_data = create_new_data(obj = elevation.spdf.reproj))

Error in locs[valid.pattern, ] : (subscript) logical subscript too long
In addition: Warning messages:
1: 'newdata' had 5006 rows but variables found have 51257 rows 
2: 'newdata' had 5006 rows but variables found have 51257 rows
```

My intuition is that my SpatialPointsDataFrame is too large (larger than the grid I want to interpolate to) and therefore the Kriging fails. I tried randomly thinning my SpatialPointsDataFrame, but the same problem still occurs when the number of elements is lower than the number of cells in `my.raster`. Curiously, the autoKrige seems to work when I thin the SpatialPointsDataFrame to exactly 23940 elements, but the computations take forever (I aborted after 36 Minutes).

I am aware of the explanations provided [here](https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/interpolation-in-r.html) and [here](https://rpubs.com/nabilabd/118172), but they both do not use the autoKrige() function.

Does someone have an idea of what is going on here and how to solve it?

System information:
R version 3.6.2 //
RStudio version 1.2.5033 //
Mac OS 10.14.6

Comment: I'm not sure we can help without a sample data set, or code to construct one. Can you put your data somewhere we can get it, or make a sample data set that illustrates the problem and reproduces your errors?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question to add code for dummy data, with which the error should be reproducible. I also added my system information.

Comment: Did not go over your entire Q/code, but take a look a this tutorial: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158021/plotting-map-resulted-from-kriging-in-r/164421#164421. Maybe it is something related to your prediction grid (and not the observed points). I saw you used `SpatialPixels` function instead of `SpatialPixelsDataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! This solved the issue.